# Text gets displayed during boot after Nvidia installtion

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, xorg, resolution

After installing latest nvidia drivers from xorg edgers ppa, the boot screen ( where it shows ubuntu logo) displays background process as text.

Is there any way to restore the default boot screen using nvidia driver.

(Note: It changes back to default logo and resolution once I change back to nouveau driver)

Comment: Issues like this are to be expected when running bleeding-edge code.  You might choose to file a bug, but I wouldn't bother unless it happens on stable code.

Comment: It also happens in the tested Nvidia driver provided by Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I'm not clear on the situation here.  You said it happened after installing the edgers drivers.  Did it work before?  Anyway, assuming you're running Unity, try reinstalling the ubuntu-desktop package, and make sure the appropriate plymouth-* packages are installed.  You also need to say what hardware you're using.

Comment: Let me clear it for you. It works fine with defult nouveau driver provide with ubuntu, but when i use either the tested nvidia driver provide by ubuntu or when i use latest nvidia driver provided by xorg edgers the problem arises.  Since Xorg provides latest driver i raised my question stating that. I am running unity, i dint add or remove any program other than the driver after my installation. I am running on Intel i5 processor with Nvidia 8400gs card

Comment: The solution they provided no longer works.When i tried it i got problem with hwinfo as it no longer avaliable.

Comment: [This post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2185023&p=12838958#post12838958) suggests the hwinfo packages from 13.04 might work.

Comment: No actually using the script broke my previous installation. i would suggest not to use it in ubuntu 14.04

Comment: The `hwinfo` is not necessary. I just can set up `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1024x768` and have Ubuntu logo during boot.

Comment: I even tried that, but no changes. Still same boot happens. I tried all methods in the above suggestion, before creating this post.As I mentioned before, some methods even broke my installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the mistake is on my part, I didn't follow the steps correctly.hwinfo method is not working, however the next one works.

1. While booting the system, press **shift** to enter into the grub and press **c** to enter into the console
2. type videoinfo
3. Note down the best supported resolution eg. 1024x768x32
4. Now press **esc** and boot normally.login and go the terminal.
5. Enter `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` .
6. A text file will open. Search for the line #GRUB_GFXMODE=
7. Replace #GRUB_GFXMODE= with

`GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768x32
 GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep`

Save the text file. Enter the following commands

`echo "FRAMEBUFFER=y" | sudo tee -a /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all 
sudo update-grub`

Thats it. Now restart the system.

I have one query though. **Why is the supported resoulution is much less that tmy screen resolution. In my case max resolution is 1600x1200x32, where as my screen resolution is 1920x1080** though it is better then the default 640x480